# How get count number of touches/actions in my total app by end user in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, touch

I want to get all touches and buttons actions count in my app to show in UI like how many actions done sofar by user. It's a Swift app.

I tried with following code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        UtilityClass.sharedInstance.touchesCount += 1
        print(UtilityClass.sharedInstance.touchesCount)
    }
```

But it's calling only `UIView` touches events, but not calling for `UIButton` actions, is there any other solutions to achieve my requirement.

If its single button action, I can call this integer to increase, but, I have number of button actions in my app, thats why I am posting this here.

Comment: I think you would  need to use `@IBAction` to count the number of button touches.

Comment: please check updated question.

Comment: You can try the same code `UtilityClass.sharedInstance.touchesCount += 1` in action of every button, right?

Comment: yes, but, if there are 100's of buttons actions, if I call this to every method, will it make good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add this to your project

```
extension UIButton {
    open override func sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, for event: UIEvent?) {
        super.sendAction(action, to: target, for: event)
        UtilityClass.sharedInstance.touchesCount += 1
        print(UtilityClass.sharedInstance.touchesCount)
    }
}
```

edit:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
extension UIButton {
    open override func sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, for event: UIEvent?) {
        super.sendAction(action, to: target, for: event)
        print("1111")
    }
}
```

above is my full test code, I have a outlet button which is `UIButton`, every time I click the button action, it will print `1111`, and if your button class is custom subclass of `UIButton`, please change `extension UIButton {` to `extension YourCustomButtonName {`

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper declare it in any file out of classes.

Comment: how can I call this to all buttons actions, you mean do I need to call this method in all button actions? if so how?

Comment: but, my custom actions of buttons are not getting called

Comment: you don't need to call this method, this method is `override` method just put the code in to your project it will work.

Comment: If I call this method, my custom method of button action, not working/calling

Comment: well, missed add `super.sendAction(action, to: target, for: event)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156438/discussion-between-anilkumar-ios-developer-and-nf-lee).